# What is the relationship between Autodesk and the MapGuide Open Source project?

Tags: open-source-gis, mapguide

In the year 2006 Autodesk started MapGuide as an open source project (MGOS). At the same time they began to develop the commercial version of MapGuide (MapGuide Enterprise MGE /Autodesk Infrastructure Map Server AIMS).

With respect to the software development: What is the relationship between Autodesk and the MapGuide Open Source project today (and in the future?)? How does Autodesk support the MapGuide Open Source community today? Are developers from Autodesk writing code for MGOS? How benefits MGOS from new features of AIMS?

Regards Jens

Answer (score 1):

MGE is the active commercial development for autodesk. Some of the MGE development can make it into MGOS.
MGOS is the open source branch from which some of the open source development can make it into MGE.